# Search by string field name

Tags: c#, .net, linq, expression

I need to build Search by string field name.

For example this code:

```
SearchProvider.Search(records, "First", "S2");
```

Should be equal to:

```
SearchProvider.Search(records, x => x.First, "S2");
```

The problem: converting string to Linq lambda expression.

How I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should convert the string to lambda expression using `Expression.Lambda` for example:

```
public IQueryable<TModel> Search<TModel>(IQueryable<TModel> model, string selector, string searchFor)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TModel), "x");
        var contains = Expression.Call(
            Expression.PropertyOrField(param, selector),
            "Contains", null, Expression.Constant(searchFor)
        );
        var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, bool>>(contains, param);

        model = model.Where(predicate);
    return model;
}
```

Next for fair search you should do two things:

- Search for any object not just strings.
- Lower all the strings.

Here is example:

```
public IQueryable<TModel> Search<TModel>(IQueryable<TModel> model, string selector, object searchFor)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TModel), "x");
    var tostring = Expression.Call(
        Expression.PropertyOrField(param, selector),
        "ToString", null, null
        );
    var tolower = Expression.Call(
        tostring,
        "ToLower", null, null
        );
    var contains = Expression.Call(
        tolower,
        "Contains", null, Expression.Constant(searchFor)
                );
    var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, bool>>(contains, param);

    model = model.Where(predicate);

        return model;
}
```

Good luck.